# Publish video on Media Services with ProgressiveDownload streaming format

Tags: c#, azure-media-services, progressive-download

I need to implement an application which is able to upload an .mp4 video on Azure Media Services. The video should be published in **ProgressiveDownload** streaming format and should be **encrypted at rest**.

Studying the Media Services documentation I tried to implement a Console application.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var tokenCredentials = new AzureAdTokenCredentials(_AADTenantDomain, AzureEnvironments.AzureCloudEnvironment);
            var tokenProvider = new AzureAdTokenProvider(tokenCredentials);

            _context = new CloudMediaContext(new Uri(_RESTAPIEndpoint), tokenProvider);

            // Add calls to methods defined in this section.
            // Make sure to update the file name and path to where you have your media file.
            IAsset inputAsset =
            UploadFile(_videoPath, AssetCreationOptions.StorageEncrypted);

            IAsset encodedAsset =
            EncodeToAdaptiveBitrateMP4s(inputAsset, AssetCreationOptions.StorageEncrypted);

            PublishAssetGetURLs(encodedAsset);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Parse the XML error message in the Media Services response and create a new
            // exception with its content.
            exception = MediaServicesExceptionParser.Parse(exception);

            Console.Error.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }       

    static public IAsset EncodeToAdaptiveBitrateMP4s(IAsset asset, AssetCreationOptions options)
    {

        // Prepare a job with a single task to transcode the specified asset
        // into a multi-bitrate asset.

        IJob job = _context.Jobs.CreateWithSingleTask(
            "Media Encoder Standard",
            "Adaptive Streaming",
            asset,
            "Adaptive Bitrate MP4",
            options);

        Console.WriteLine("Submitting transcoding job...");


        // Submit the job and wait until it is completed.
        job.Submit();

        job = job.StartExecutionProgressTask(
            j =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Job state: {0}", j.State);
                Console.WriteLine("Job progress: {0:0.##}%", j.GetOverallProgress());
            },
            CancellationToken.None).Result;

        Console.WriteLine("Transcoding job finished.");

        IAsset outputAsset = job.OutputMediaAssets[0];

        return outputAsset;
    }

    static public void PublishAssetGetURLs(IAsset asset)
    {
        // Publish the output asset by creating an Origin locator for adaptive streaming,
        // and a SAS locator for progressive download.

        IAssetDeliveryPolicy policy =
            _context.AssetDeliveryPolicies.Create("Clear Policy",
            AssetDeliveryPolicyType.NoDynamicEncryption,
            AssetDeliveryProtocol.ProgressiveDownload | AssetDeliveryProtocol.HLS | AssetDeliveryProtocol.SmoothStreaming | AssetDeliveryProtocol.Dash, 
            null);

        asset.DeliveryPolicies.Add(policy);

        _context.Locators.Create(
            LocatorType.OnDemandOrigin,
            asset,
            AccessPermissions.Read,
            TimeSpan.FromDays(30));

        _context.Locators.Create(
            LocatorType.Sas,
            asset,
            AccessPermissions.Read,
            TimeSpan.FromDays(30));


        IEnumerable<IAssetFile> mp4AssetFiles = asset
                .AssetFiles
                .ToList()
                .Where(af => af.Name.EndsWith(".mp4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        // Get the Smooth Streaming, HLS and MPEG-DASH URLs for adaptive streaming,
        // and the Progressive Download URL.
        Uri smoothStreamingUri = asset.GetSmoothStreamingUri();
        Uri hlsUri = asset.GetHlsUri();
        Uri mpegDashUri = asset.GetMpegDashUri();

        // Get the URls for progressive download for each MP4 file that was generated as a result
        // of encoding.
        List<Uri> mp4ProgressiveDownloadUris = mp4AssetFiles.Select(af => af.GetSasUri()).ToList();                       
    }
```

This code stopped working when I added the part to manage encryption at rest. More precisely when I:

- replaced `UploadFile(_videoPath, AssetCreationOptions.None);` with `UploadFile(_videoPath, AssetCreationOptions.StorageEncrypted);`
- replaced `EncodeToAdaptiveBitrateMP4s(inputAsset, AssetCreationOptions.None);` with `EncodeToAdaptiveBitrateMP4s(inputAsset, AssetCreationOptions.StorageEncrypted);`
- added the following code in `PublishAssetGetURLs` method

  IAssetDeliveryPolicy policy =
              _context.AssetDeliveryPolicies.Create("Clear Policy",
              AssetDeliveryPolicyType.NoDynamicEncryption,
              AssetDeliveryProtocol.ProgressiveDownload | AssetDeliveryProtocol.HLS | AssetDeliveryProtocol.SmoothStreaming | AssetDeliveryProtocol.Dash, 
              null);

  ```
      asset.DeliveryPolicies.Add(policy);
  ```

The problem is that the video is correctly uploaded, but when I try to play the video right inside Azure Portal I get a generic 0x0 error.

Comment: Question - you want the content to be protected and encrypted at rest, but you are willing to hand out URLs to the content that are unprotected and stream the content out in the clear?  What scenario are you solving for exactly?  Are you concerned that your content will be stolen, pirated, etc? In which case, why publish the content as Clear?  
Storage encryption is primarly a feature for customers that are using DRM and need to meet MPAA guidelines.  If you just need storage encryption, turn on server side storage encryption on your Storage account and upload in the clear.

Comment: Actually the requirement is delivering protected contents and I previously implemented delivering by Smooth Streaming plus Dynamic Encryption. Solution works, but I am facing other technical problems that forced me to consider Progressive Download which unfortunately doesn't allow Dynamic Encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Id avoid progressive download if you need it to be protected.  Unless you are building an offline protected download solution. If that is the case we just added some new articles in our documentation that shows how to do Playready, Widevine, and Fairpoay offline DRM. 
Check out the content protection section of our docs for those articles.